# How to change recursive into a while loop statement(i.e iteratative)

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was studying a linked list code and came across the fact that apart from using recursive, a for or while loop can also be used. Therefore, I tried changing the recursive into a while loop(i.e iterative) but it seems my logic is completely out of place..

I just want to change the `listing` function in the following code. Could you please help me out?

The recursive code is as follows(This is the code which has the result I want):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linkedlist{
    char first;
    struct linkedlist *second;
}linkedlist;
typedef linkedlist *NODE;


NODE listing(char string[]){  //This is the function that needs to change using a loop.
    NODE head;
    if(string[0] == '\0')
    return NULL;
    else{
        head = (struct linkedlist *)malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
        head -> first = string[0];
        head -> second = listing(string + 1);
        return head;
    } 
} 

void print(NODE head){
    if(head == NULL)
    printf("NULL\n");
    else{
        printf("%c -> ", head -> first);
        print(head -> second);
    }
}

int main(void){
    char in_string[10];
    NODE head;
    printf("insert a string : ");
    scanf("%s", in_string);
    head = listing(in_string);
    printf("result of the list...\n");
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

The result of the recursive code is that if I input `trial`, it would give me the result of `t -> r -> i -> a -> l -> NULL`.

The code I tried to change and ended up as resulting in an error is as follows:

```
NODE listing(char string[]){
   NODE head;
   int i = 0;
   while(1){
      if(string[i] == '\0'){
         return NULL;
      }
      else{
         head = (struct linkedlist *)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
         head -> first = string[i];
         i++;
         return head;
      }
   }
}
```

I'm really struggling with this for hours... Please would you help me how to change it so I get the same results?

Comment: You never assign to `second` anywhere in your iterative function, how do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a non-recursive function using the while loop is enough simple.

```
NODE listing( const char string[] )
{
    NODE head = NULL;
    NODE *current = &head;

    while ( *string )
    {
        *current = ( struct linkedlist * )malloc( sizeof( linkedlist ) );
        ( *current ) -> first = *string++;
        ( *current ) -> second = NULL;
        current = &( *current )->second;
    }

    return head; 
}
```

Pay attention to that using a typedef for pointers like this

```
typedef linkedlist *NODE;
```

is not a good idea. It can only confuse readers of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
NODE listing(char string[]){ 
    NODE head;
    head = (struct linkedlist *)malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
    NODE cur = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i] != '\0')
    {
        cur->first = string[i];
        if (string[i+1] != '\0') cur->second = (struct linkedlist *)malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
        else cur->second = NULL;
        cur = cur->second;
        i++;
    } 
    return head;
}

int main(void){
    char in_string[10] = {0};
    memcpy(in_string, "trial", 5);
    NODE head = listing(in_string);
    print(head);     //==> t -> r -> i -> a -> l -> NULL
    return 0;
}
```